# Converting RestTemplate exchange to okHttpClient call

Tags: java, spring, okhttp, resttemplate

I am trying to replace ResteTemplate in a spring boot application with OkHttpClient.

Here is my code with the RestTemplate from Spring:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + config.getScope(), headers);

ResponseEntity<Token> resp = getRestTemplate(builder).exchange(
      new URI(config.getTokenUrl()),
      HttpMethod.POST,
      httpEntity,
      Token.class);
```

And here is my attempt to map that code with OkHttpClient:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("body", "grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + config.getScope())
                    .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .url("http://" + config.getTokenUrl())
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

OkHttpClient client = buildOkHttpClient();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).close();
```

The problem is that I get an error `Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed`. 
The Http Method is POST as seen in the RestTemplate.

But I am not sure how should I map/transform the `HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=" + config.getScope(), headers);` to conform to OkHttp? 
Maybe the mistake is here?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-okhttp#post-request) and this construction:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new FormBody.Builder()
  .add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
  .add("scope", config.getScope())
  .build();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://" + config.getTokenUrl())
  .post(requestBody)
  .build();
```